# Equation of a line that form a triangle of area 8

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

Find the equation of the line that passes through the intersection of two lines, $\ 3x-4y=0$ and $\ 2x-5y+7=0$, and form a triangle of area 8 with the coordinate axes.

I know that the intersection point of those lines is $\ (4,3)$. But how can I find the equation of the new line that form the triangle of area 8?

Comment: Well, consider all lines that pass through the point $(4,3)$. The only parameter will be the slope of this line. It's useful to draw a diagram of this. The slope should be negative, so that it forms a triangle with the coordinate axes. Calculate the intersection points with the coordinate axes (easy) and set the area of the formed triangle to 8.

Answer (score 2):

The vertices of the triangle are $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ where $a$, $b>0$
such that $ab=16$. Can you (i) find the equation of the line $L$ through $(a,0)$
and $(0,16/a)$ (in terms of $a$) and (ii) the value of $a$ that makes $(4,3)$
lie on $L$?

Comment: Not really. I can't see what you are asking. I tried using the intercept forms and solving for _b_  and then replace it in the area equation $\ 16=a(b)$  but it gave me a no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let the desired line be$$\frac xa+\frac yb=1$$The intersection point $(4,3)$ lies on it, so$$\frac4a+\frac3b=1$$The area of the triangle formed by the line and the coordinate axes is $\frac12|ab|=8\implies|ab|=16$. Now evaluate the cases $ab>0$ and $ab<0$. The former gives no solution while the latter gives $(a,b)=(8/3,-6),(-8,2)$.

[image]

Comment: But when I graph the points the area of the triangle gave me 16, and should be 8. Sorry, I think I don't get it!

Comment: @eniid You graphed it wrong. I have added the image of the graph. Perhaps you forgot to divide the product of $ab$ by $2$?

Comment: when I graph the equations of the image the area still gave me 16. But if I graph $ (x/-8)+(y/2) =1$ and $(8x/3) -(y/6)=1$  the area of the triangle form gave me 8.  If I am doing something wrong I will appreciate if you can show me step by step because it driven me crazy.

Comment: Here is a link of a image of my graph. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1na64-0QNdSsyk5YZzMyRhM05O_gBxy2t/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @eniid In the image you linked the equation of second line is wrong. It should be $3x/8$, not $8x/3$. Can you tell me how you get the area 16? Just the calculation.

Comment: I used GeoGebra to find the area of the triangle.   [link](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/hqhsrsyn)

Comment: Btw how you get that $(a,b)=(8/3,−6),(−8,2)$?

Answer (score 0):

The equation of any straight line  passing through the intersection of $$3x-4y=0$$ and $$2x-5y+7=0$$

is $$0=k(3x-4y)+(2x-5y+7)\iff(3k+2)x-y(4k+5)=-7$$

$$x\cdot\dfrac{3k+2}{-7}+y\cdot\dfrac{4k+5}7=1$$

So, we need $$8=\dfrac{\left|\dfrac{3k+2}{-7}\cdot\dfrac{4k+5}7\right|}2$$

$$\implies16\cdot49|(3k+2)(4k+5)|$$

$$\implies(3k+2)(4k+5)=\pm16\cdot49$$

$k=?$

Comment: If I solve that I will have $\ 12k^2 +23k+799=0$ or $\ 12k^2 +23k+779=0$, doing quadratic formula to solve for _k_ it gave me a no real solution.  I'm doing something wrong?